# create video from hand drawing

Tags: video, time-lapse

I have a hand drawn image. How can I create a video out of it like this?

What other options would you recommend? I want to create a presentation

Comment: Added video to answer to demo setup

Comment: can i insert my own drawings? just wondering if it would also accept arabic fonts from right to left

Comment: @Adel - I don't see any posts talking about using fonts.  Generally this uses strokes which would be whatever you drew in to it.  It could go in any direction you want.

Answer (score 3):

To create video from hand drawn images, you will need to prepare yourself for drawing a lot more images, as you likely need one for every frame, which you then photograph as a single image. When there images are combined you get the effect of movement.

It's a lot like the old fashioned flick books we used to draw at school- with a slightly changed picture at the corner of each page so that when you riffle the pages you get the effect of continuous movement.

There are some video packages that will let you build a virtual model and overlay your images onto the model so you can animate it etc. But you will be talking big bucks, and steep learning curves.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this:

- You need a drawing board (Wacom or similar)
- Record screen while drawing on the table with a screen-recording software. Only the drawing surface on the screen.
- Then record some small segments with your arm holding a pen over a green or blue sheet of paper that is evenly lit.
- in a video composition software make a matte for the arm
- Put the arm with the pen over the recorded screen capture and animate it so that the pen appear to follow the line. Variate to make it look realistic.
- Speed up everything
- Render out to finished video

UPDATE: To demo what's described, this will be about the result (although simplified demo, you will see the basic principle.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fast and basic workflow using Adobe Illustrator and After Effects, basic knowledge is needed.

Convert your cartoons or artworks to vectors first, probably in Adobe Illustrator. Then select the paths and copy them.

In Adobe After Effects create a new composition and a new solid layer (any color). Select your solid and paste (Cmd or Ctrl + V) your paths. This will create masks on your solid layer and your solid layer will look like your Vector graphics.

Select your solid and apply `Effect > Generate > Stroke`. In `Effect Controls` panel you need to modify some of the Stroke Effect's parameters:

1. Check `All Masks` option
2. Check `Stroke Sequenially` option
3. Select `On Transparent` under `Paint Style`.
4. Edit the `Color`, `Brush Hardness`, `Opacity` and `Brush Size` parameters to meet your taste.

Now you must add keyframes to the `End` parameter to animate your illustration. On frame 0 (or 1) add a keyframe with a value of 0%. Move a few seconds (or the length of your desired animation), set another keyframe with a value of 100%.

Your illustration is now animated.

If you need the hand, you can either find a stock footage or take a photo of your hand holding a pen. Cut it out in Photoshop/GIMP etc. Then you can animate it in After Effects.

You have many options to do that animation but if you are a novice, there are no easier methods to create an OK result.

Edit: By the way, if you need to scale your illustration up, your layer's `Continuously Rasterize` switch should be turned on to maintain the smoothness. It's that sun like icon, I can not add a screenshot at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully, you'll see that the hand it's not actually drawing. The effect is acomplished by several images from the hand in distinct poses, following the lines as they are painted.

Images like [these](http://www.rgbstock.com/images/writing%20hand) could be used as a layer on top of the drawing.

Then the areas of the drawing could be successively cut to diferent layers and then hidden or shown as needed to give the ilusion that they are being drawn on the paper.

You could try any image editing software, then import the key frames to any video editing tool, and tweak each key frame time duration to give the right speed to the hand

**Update:**

Most video editing tools would give the option to move only the hand following a path between two key frames, wich could make things easier

Answer (score 0):

Well!! This is my first video that I created through paper drawings.

I used 3d max for character animation, which took 1 day since rendering takes time. I snapped my drawings and highlighted their boundaries in Adobe flash.

But I believe this process is bit length for people like me who are not professional in flash, photoshop etc.

So I found another software **VideoScribe**. You take snap of your drawings and import them in to video scribes thats all. It'll put sketching effect, coloring effects by its own. However, I still miss Flash since motion, animation are not possible with VedioScribe.